# Given a string , find the longest substring with atmost two distinct characters . if there are multiple matching strings return the first string

Tags: java

Java : find the substring from given string with two distinct characters and if there are multiple matching strings return the first string.

**Whenever i am trying the below code getting output as ddddeddeee but i need output as aaaadddd. Please help**

Used below Java code 
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

class testlongdistinct {

```
public static final int CHAR_RANGE = 128;

public static String longestSubstr(String str, int k) {

    int end = 0, begin = 0;

    Set<Character> window = new HashSet<>();

    int[] freq = new int[CHAR_RANGE];

    for (int low = 0, high = 0; high < str.length(); high++) {
        window.add(str.charAt(high));
        freq[str.charAt(high)]++;

        while (window.size() > k) {

            if (--freq[str.charAt(low)] == 0) {
                window.remove(str.charAt(low));
            }

            low++; // reduce window size
        }

        if (end - begin < high - low) {
            end = high;
            begin = low;
        }
    }

    return str.substring(begin, end + 1);
}

// main function
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "aaabbbccaaaaddddeddeee";
    int k = 2;

    System.out.print(longestSubstr(str, k));

}
```

}

Comment: Is this homework? it looks like homework (and badly formatted).

Comment: I think your program is correct - "ddddeddeee" is a better answer than "aaaadddd" because it has at most 2 characters and is longer than the latter

Comment: I'm sorry but this is not the kind of question for SO. You can debug it to find why. Other persons too need to debug it to find why it output this resut. It does not need any extra knowledge or so.